# What does self point to in a Ruby scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I created a scope like the following:

```
scope :except_me, -> { where( "id != ?", self.id ) }
```

But this code produces an error: no attribute ID for class blah.  What does self point to inside a scope and how do I correct this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self in a scope points to the class itself, not an instance. 
You need to pass the instance to the scope to exclude it from your query:

```
scope :except, -> item { where( "id != ?", item.id ) }
```